# How do I get the "meta-data" of my service

Tags: android, service, metadata

I have metadata in the AndroidManifest.xml for my service.  Getting this metadata is fairly straightforward in an activity, as all you have to do is something like this:

```
final Bundle data =
getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(this.getComponentName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).metaData;
```

For services, I would obviously be using the 'getServiceInfo()' method instead of the activity info, but there is no 'getComponentName()' method in a Service.  Is there any reason why this isn't available? Do I have to construct my own ComponentName object here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to construct my own ComponentName object here?

AFAIK, yes. From a `Service`, `new ComponentName(this, this.getClass())` should give you a `ComponentName` for the service itself.

Answer (score 10):

```java
ComponentName myService = new ComponentName(this, this.getClass());
Bundle data = getPackageManager().getServiceInfo(myService, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).metaData;
```